# GroupBy multiple columns in Linq with Take()

Tags: c#, linq

I have an entity that looks like this:

```
public class Entries
{
    public Contract Contract { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}

public class Contract
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to query the database and return an object that would allow me to report on the Contract data like this where the numbers for each year are counts for that year:

```
Contract ID/Name    2015      2016
1 - ABC              12         4
2 - XYZ              17         76
3 - QRS              414        0
```

I've started with Linq like this:

```
var results = context.Entries
    .Include(x => x.Contract)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Contract, x.Year })
    .Select(x => new { Contract = x.Key.Contract, Year = x.Key.Year, Count = x.Count() })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Contract.Number)
    .Take(5).ToList();
```

I would like this single IQueryable to set me up to push the data into an object that mimics the table above.  I'm having trouble setting it up, though, because of the `Take()`.  I only want to show the first 5 results, but when I apply it like I've done above after grouping, using the example data given, there will be one record for ABC 2015 and one record for ABC 2016.  I'm not sure the best way to use `GroupBy()` and `Take()` together to accomplish my goal.

Comment: You want top 5 based on what? What if some contract has a high value in 2015 but 0 in 2016?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I want 5 contracts results max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a nested collection:

```
var results = context.Entries
    .Include(x => x.Contract)
    .GroupBy(t=>t.Contract)
    .Select(t=>new{
        Contract=t.Key,
        Years=t.GroupBy(s=>s.Year)
            .Select(s=>new{
               Year=s.Key,
               Count=s.Count()
            })
        })
     .Take(5);
```

You'll have a IEnumerable of pairs of Contract/Years where Years is an IEnumerable of year / count pairs with the counts per year.

Comment: Now I'm getting a `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.Int32,System.Int32] ToDictionary...` exception.

Comment: Oops. Then remove the ToDictionary call. I'll update the answer. Sorry about that. Another option is to enumerate the IEnumerable before calling ToDictionary.